# many lambdas vs fastapi/express

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I recently came into the amazing thing called FaaS.
I want to migrate my current express API server to AWS lambdas but I can decide the right architecture. After hours of searching, I couldn't find the best practice to do so.

My API has more than 50 endpoints, the big options are to manage 50 lambdas managed by AWS API Gateways and serverless framework, or divide my server into a few fast API/express lambdas that each one will have about 10 endpoints.

Each way has an advantage and disadvantages like -

1. The number of cold starts I will have to face trow.
2. The cost of maintaining of the number of functions.
3. The "throw" of the API Gateways that can manage my JWT tokens, parsing the request and response, and more of that things.

I will be very happy if someone can make any sense here, I read so many articles that made me more confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to add all of your endpoints to one lambda, and wrap that with API gateway for your auth.

Comment: What @rleffler said… That is what you should do. Check out https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express as a way to use your existing app on Lambda.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. API gateways can't decide which function will run inside the lambda, that mean that any other solution (like serverless-express you sent) is going to manage the calls it self and that takes out the benefits of the AWS frameworks

Comment: You use API Gateway and set up a lambda proxy.  This way your gateway calls your lambda to connect to all of your endpoints.  So you only have one function where all of your endpoints live, but your gateway calls them via the proxy.  Your gateway handles the auth before passing it along with the token, or however you set it up. There are still many benefits of doing it this way: cost vs EC2, auto scaling, auth in front, ...